# Accidentally enabled an autocomplete list which is slowing everything down

Tags: ssms, ssms-2012

I was typing too fast and accidentally pressed some key combo which enabled this monstrosity:

[image]

I still want local members to autocomplete as before, but this is overkill; it lists all available databases, tables, functions, etc. Disabling Intellisense doesn't do anything either. How do I turn this off?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is actually a third party plugin called "ApexSQL" that came preinstalled on my machine. I disabled it from the top menu.